# Слитно или раздельно

Tags: орфография

Читаю описание к маске для лица: "глубокоочищающая". Но разве это слово должно писаться слитно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово **глубокоочищающий** может употребляться как сложный термин (имя прилагательное), и тогда требуется слитное написание. Например, *маломинерализованный, глубокозалегающий, глубоколежащий, глубокосидящий, глубокоочищенный*. Если такие слова употребляются не как термины, то по правилам русского языка необходимо раздельное написание.
Что касается конкретно вашего случая, то, возможно, имеется в виду как раз терминологическое употребление слова, ведь вы упомянули, что речь идет об описании к косметическому препарату. Поэтому "*глубокоочищающая маска*" написано слитно.
Пример контекста, когда данное слово пишется раздельно: *глубоко очищающая поры (кожу) маска*. Появление зависимого слова сразу выделяет причастие *очищающая* и требует раздельного написания. (По материалам энциклопедии "Слитно, раздельно, через дефис" под ред. Т.Н.Гурьевой, Полного орфографического словаря русского языка под ред.В.В. Лопатина.)